# Display a specific digit within a string

Tags: python

What is the best way to display a specific decimal place in a string. So 23.54 and print only 4. Right now I'm doing this but it dont seem very effective.

```
money=input("how much money")

totalmoney=(float(money))

totalmoney1=(float("{:.1f}".format(totalmoney)))

totalmoney2=(float("{:.2f}".format(totalmoney)))

totalmoney3 =(round(totalmoney2 - totalmoney1,2))

totalmoney4=(abs(totalmoney3))

print(totalmoney4*100, "cents")
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Do you want to extract the string after ```.``` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want...

```
print(input('How much money? ').split('.')[-1]['your-index-goes-here'])
# this code will still work if there's no decimal point
```

For eg.

```
print(str(23.54).split('.')[-1][2]) # returns '4'
```

Tell me if there's any errors...

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the **String** at the **decimal** and then access whatever **decimal place** you want.

For example, **-1** can be used to access the **last Decimal place**.

```
money = input('How much Money: ')
cents = money.split('.')[-1] if '.' in money else 0
print(cents[-1])
```

(**Note**: This code sample will not work as expected if there is no decimal place given.)

Answer (score 0):

if I'd understood your question correctly, you want the second digit after floating point. I guess you could use something like

```
str(round(totalmoney,2))[-1]
```

please let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

you multiply a string by 10 and print it, you'll see 10 strings.